# Issue in pointing domain to hosting server folder

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my shared hosting server on godaddy.com and primary domain is abc.com
Now I have another domain registered xyz.com on some other 3rd service not on godaddy. For this new website xyz.com I have installed wordpress in xyz directory of my godaddy hosting server.

Now how do I point this xyz.com domain to my xyz directory of my hosting server by keeping abc.com website as it is?

Answer (score 0):

B"H

I think URL Masking is what you're looking for. Some domain providers include this in CPanel.

<strike>You can also achieve this via [.htaccess](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url)</strike>

Alternatively, you can try [frames](https://www.siteground.com/kb/simple_domain_name_masking/), though not recommended.

**UPDATE**
You can also consider using [apache as a proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/510758/how-to-pass-a-request-from-one-apache-server-to-another), though using an A or CNAME record to accomplish this is the right way.

Comment: how do i achieve this via .htaccess? Can you give me syntax?

Comment: .htaccess may not just work for this. If your domain management console doesn't allow this, you may want to consider importing it into Google Domains